# How to get information when 500 error

Tags: php, guzzle

```
<?php

$this->client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;

try {
    $response = $this->client->request('get', $url);
    $result = json_decode($response->getBody());
    Log::save($result);
} catch (RequestException $e) {
    Log::save($e->getMessage());
}
```

If the target page has internal server error 500 situation, I will get the error message `Client error: 404`, actually the target page has show what the bug is if I use the browser to open it, I want to save those PHP error message to log, but I don't know how to got when using Guzzle.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different ways you can proceed:

1. If you are using Guzzle 6+ and you are using the default
   HandlerStack (creating the client with no handler `new \GuzzleHttp\Client()`; the default behaviour will be for the request
   to throw a `GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException` exception.  In this case, all you have to do is wrap your request in a try / catch block (as shown above).
2. If you are manually creating your 
   HandlerStack `$stack = new \GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack(); $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['handler' => > $stack,])`; then the `\GuzzleHttp\Middleware::httpErrors` middleware has not been loaded onto the stack, and you will have to trap it within your own middleware or by passing a callable to the 'on_headers' request option.

References:

1. [Guzzle Request Options - http_errors](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/request-options.html#http-errors)
2. [Guzzle Handlers and Middleware](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/handlers-and-middleware.html)
3. [Guzzle Request Options - on_headers](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/request-options.html#on-headers)

Comment: I just find out the answewr, I can echo `$e->getResponse()->getBody()` to get the information